# AddressSanitizer Error Location Missing with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning, address-sanitizer

This command `gcc uaf.c -o uaf -fsanitize=address -static-libasan` doesn't display AddressSanitizer summary error location.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *s = malloc(100);
    free(s);
    strcpy(s, "Hello world!");
    printf("string is: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I see:

```
 =================================================================
    ==1017908==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60b0000000f0 at pc 0x5623a332bb53 bp 0x7fff85504890 sp 0x7fff85504038
    WRITE of size 13 at 0x60b0000000f0 thread T0
        #0 0x5623a332bb52 in memcpy (/home/test/work/uaf+0x1db52)
        #1 0x5623a33ebcd5 in main (/home/test/work/uaf+0xddcd5)
        #2 0x7f226558ad8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)
        #3 0x7f226558ae3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f)
        #4 0x5623a33163a4 in _start (/home/test/work/uaf+0x83a4)
    
    0x60b0000000f0 is located 0 bytes inside of 100-byte region [0x60b0000000f0,0x60b000000154)
    freed by thread T0 here:
        #0 0x5623a33a5da7 in free (/home/test/work/uaf+0x97da7)
        #1 0x5623a33ebcba in main (/home/test/work/uaf+0xddcba)
        #2 0x7f226558ad8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)
    
    previously allocated by thread T0 here:
        #0 0x5623a33a60f7 in malloc (/home/test/work/uaf+0x980f7)
        #1 0x5623a33ebcaa in main (/home/test/work/uaf+0xddcaa)
        #2 0x7f226558ad8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)
    
    SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free (/home/test/work/uaf+0x1db52) in memcpy
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
```

**This is what I expect in the summary part:**

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /home/test/work/uaf.c:8 in memcpy
```

What am I missing here?

I'm using this blog for reference https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_use_address_sanitizer

Comment: `-g` apparently. Where else would line number information come from?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI thanks I tried 

`gcc uaf.c -o uaf -fsanitize=address -static-libasan -g` 
and 
 `gcc uaf.c -o uaf -fsanitize=address -g`

the latter gives better results... not too sure why `-static-libasan` has to be removed

Comment: What is CC in the title? BTW the tag [tag:c++] was used improperly, the shown code is an invalid C++ and does not compile.

Comment: Can't reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/4rseaqv8v. You seem to run an old gcc/address sanitizer that needs to run with its symbolizer.

Comment: CC is a typo it should be gcc

Comment: @273K on the same system I the Go compiler is able to use address sanitizer using CGo which uses gcc gets back the error location. go build -asan example.go

I'm trying to figure out what magic Go does to make this work

Comment: What does `gcc --version` say? Also, why are you using `-static-libasan`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0`
I only used `-static-libasan` because it was suggested in the blog. But seems like this is unnecessary

Comment: @gopher I just tried with `gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0` and got the same result as you, until I added `-g`. You could also try with `-ggdb` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @TedLyngmo @273K I'm also trying to understand why certain flags might prevent `-g` from working and giving us file error location. Is there an easy explanation?

Comment: @gopher Not that I know of. I used the same options as you used and it worked. I think one needed to explicitly link with `-lasan` first of all libs in older `gcc`s but if that had been the case here, you wouldn't have gotten any asan output at all I think. You could upgrade to gcc 12.3.0 and try that I guess.